# Changing the argument types on a block callback

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I recently saw some example code in a WWDC video from an Apple engineer. He was using `NSArray`'s `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method, but I noticed the first argument to the block was not `id` as I'm used to, but had been changed to the concrete type that the developer knew was in the array.

For example, I just gave this a go in Xcode and everything works correctly:

```
NSArray *test = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
[test enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *aString, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // ...
}];
```

The declaration for `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` declares the first block argument to be of type `id`:

```
- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block
```

Now I understand that `id` can be used to represent any objective-c type, but this little trick with arguments was unknown to me.

Is there any documentation for this feature of the language? Can this be used in regular methods where you have an `(id)sender` argument too? Is this even safe or fully supported?

Comment: In my opinion, that should at least give you a warning.  The API is saying it could give you any object type whereas your declaration is saying you only accept a string.

Comment: I actually tested this with all the warnings you can imagine and everything was reported as OK.

Comment: which I think should be a compiler bug, although it occurs to me now that it mirrors the `for (... in ...)` control statment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link to apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW1) about `id` type.
This trick can be used in any method sending id, and it's safe, as long as you're **sure** about a type, or check it before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much equal to:

```
[test enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *aString = (NSString*)obj;
    // ...
}];
```

Notice that there is a clear parallel in fast-enumerated for loops:

```
for (id obj in test) {
    NSString *aString = (NSString*)obj;
    // ...
}
```

vs:

```
for (NSString *aString in test) {
    // ...
}
```

No links to the docs, though - sorry!